# Proper way to have type param for the implementation class

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to build some kind of base class for some hierarchical structure.  I want developers to be able to have their own implementation without repeating the hierarchical stuff.

This is a simplified example of mine:

```
interface Node<N extends Node> {
    N getParent();
    List<N> getChildren();
    void addChild(N child);
    void traverse(NodeTraverser<N> traverser);
}

abstract class AbstractNode<N extends AbstractNode> implements Node<N> {
    private N parent;
    private List<N> children;

    @Override
    public N getParent() { return parent; }

    @Override
    public List<N> getChildren() { return children; }

    @Override
    public void addChild(N child) {
         child.setParent(this);       // ** Problem Here **
         this.children.add(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void traverse(NodeTraverser<N> traverser) {
         traverser.visit(this);       // ** Problem Here **
         for(N child: children) {
             child.traverse(traverser);
         }
    }
}
```

The reason I am having `N` as the type param is, I want the concrete class of `Node` be able to make use of the actual type of the concrete class (e.g. when returning `parent`), and the `NodeTraverser` can also work against the actual implementation.  So that impl look something like this:

```
class Employee extends AbstractNode<Employee> {
    //... some Employee specific methods
}

// traverse will look like:
employee.traverse( new NodeTraverser<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public void visit(Employee employee) {
        System.out.println("employee name " + employee.getName() 
                           + " and parent " + employee.getParent().getName());
    }
}
```

However there is a problem at the `AbstractNode` as I marked in the source code.   Because this is of type `AbstractNode` and it doesn't conform to `N`, which makes compilation fail.  My workaround is to make a new protected method in `AbstractNode` like `protected N thisNode() { return (N) this; }`  and replace my access of `this` to `thisNode()`.  It works but it looks ugly to me because of the unsafe cast and inability to avoid passing type that is not the type of actual impl.

What should be the right way to infer the type of implementation in the abstract class?